# No instance created by SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a problem with SQL Server 2008 R2, when I try to connect to server it gives me the following message:

> TITLE: Connect to Server
>
> Cannot connect to (local).
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
>   (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2)

I found a couple of solutions for this, one of which told me to go the configuration manager and check the instance created by SQL Server. There was none. I found only this:

[image]

I need to learn SQL Server for a job, and I don't know what to do.

-- UPDATE --

I reinstalled SQL Server 2008 and some errors might have something to do with my issue..

[errors in reinstalling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8SZJ.jpg)

note: the first time I installed I was basically clueless, I might had the same errors before and I simply didn't notice..

Comment: Are you on your company's VPN?

Comment: No, I'm on my personal PC..

Comment: It seems you installed only client tools and not the database engine.

Comment: Your SQL server is also on your personal PC? You're just trying to set one up there to learn how to use it, I guess?

Comment: Yes, I learned SQL queries over a web based SQL virtual compiler, And now I'm trying to learn the actual DBMS..

Comment: So, to Dan's point, are you sure that you installed the database?

Comment: I'm pretty sure, I'm reinstalling it now.. Just to be sure

Comment: However, how would I tell if I didn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems you only install SQL Server Management studio not whole SQL Server DBMS so you need to install SQL Server and then try again.To check that SQL Server is installed on my PC or not You can follow these Steps

```
1.In Window Run Type `services.msc` 
2.Check that SQL Server Service is present or not
3.If Present Then Check in Running Mode or not.
4.if not here still SQL Server is not installed
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks, this worked after I reinstalled my windows.. I think my former windows version was incomplete somehow..

Answer (score 0):

You need to install SQL server and SQL Server studio management tool. Seems you are trying to install SQL Server 2008.

- Go to this link and download the version of SQL Server 2008 you are after
  32 or 64 bit
  https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=1695
- Then install a Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Management Studio.
  https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=7593

If you have windows 8.1 and upwards you can install the newer version of MSSQL which comes with Management studio. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads.